# How to resize a scene size in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I want to autoscale the size of my scene because in my GameScene.sks I can choose a few iPhone models for the scene size only (iPhone 4s, iPhone SE, iPhone 6s and iPhone 6 Plus). So I try to autoscale to support all models automatically.

This is the code in my SKScene:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

override init(size: CGSize) {

    super.init(size: size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
.......
```

The syntax seems to be correct but when I switch into the GameScene in the simulator the app will crash. I'm a beginner, so it could be that the override init function is used wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let backgroundNode = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        backgroundNode.size = CGSize(width: displaySize.width, height: displaySize.height)
        backgroundNode.color = .red
        self.addChild(backgroundNode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you set the scaleMode in the GameViewController within the viewDidLoad() method instead of setting each sizes manually. You can set scaleMode to aspectFill/ aspectFit/ resizeFill, etc.. Here is a sample code.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scene =
      GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
  }
```

Here is the document Scaling a Scene's Content to Fit the View.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/scaling_a_scene_s_content_to_fit_the_view